# API Gateway to NLB encryption in traansit

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am currently using API Gateway as public facing then it proxies to an NLB. Clients communicate to the API Gateway via SSL like https://api.example.com where https scheme is required therefore making the transit from client to API Gateway as encrypted.

Now my concern is, is my proxied traffic from API Gaateway to NLB also encrypted? I can not see find a precise answer on the internet. If it is not encrypted then how to encrypt it?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it is not encrypted because the API Gateway performs SSL termination.  You should configure [backend SSL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html) if you want the rest of the downstream flow encrypted.

Comment: Seems like "backend SSL" is the way to encrypt the transit from API gateway to a microservice application. Where will just act as a middleware between.